# update column values to reflect other column values having two different size dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two data frames.

df_1:

```
unique_id amount
1         NaN
2         5
```

df_2:

```
unique_id amount city     email 
1         90     Kansas   True
2        100     Miami    False
3        NaN     Kent     True
4        123     Newport  True
```

I would like to only update the amount column where unique_id is 1 or 2 or any other that might match on unique_id. The output should be:

```
   unique_id amount city     email 
    1        NaN     Kansas   True
    2        5       Miami    False
    3        NaN     Kent     True
    4        123     Newport  True
```

I've tried merging and contacting but I am not getting the desired result. I just want an idea of what the best approach is when two data frames are of different sizes and want to update certain column values. Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `mask`:

```
df_2['amount'] = df_2['amount'].mask(df_2['unique_id'].isin(df_1['unique_id']), 
                                     df_2['unique_id'].map(df_1.set_index('unique_id')['amount'])
                                    )
```

Output:

```
   unique_id  amount     city  email
0          1     NaN   Kansas   True
1          2     5.0    Miami  False
2          3     NaN     Kent   True
3          4   123.0  Newport   True
```